# Select From tbl1 not listed in tbl2

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make MySQL query to select records from `TBL1` not listed in `TBL2`, but not working with my query.

```
SELECT deleted_guids.guid_type
     , HEX(data_table.guid_id) as guid_id
     , HEX(data_table.guid_type) as guid_type
FROM data_table 
LEFT JOIN deleted_guids 
     ON     data_table.guid_id = deleted_guids.guid_id 
        AND data_table.guid_type = deleted_guids.guid_type 
WHERE deleted_guids.guid_type = NULL;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change `= NULL` to `IS NULL` at the end; that's the correct syntax. See [working with `NULL` values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html).